# Manter layout de banner na tela, entre um iPhone 4 e um iPhone 5

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard, iphone

Estou com um problema ao desenvolver o layout do app. No storyboard, eu adicionei um `UIImageView` para exibir algumas imagens enquanto o app estiver funcionando. Esta imagen fica na parte de baixo da tela, como um rodapé. Porém quando simulo em um iPhone de tela menor, no caso o iPhone 4 o banner some, pois fica na diferença de área das telas entre o iPhone 4 e iPhone 5.

Gostaria de saber se há um modo de manter esse layout, que o `UIImageView` seja alocado um pouco mais para cima, quando a tela do app for menor e possa aparecer.

Comment: Olá Tiago, você está usando o `AutoLayout`?

Comment: Tiago Amaral, desabilita o AutoLayout e testa.

Comment: Ok Vou testar! Mas acredito que terei que fazer mais configurações...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiago,

1 - Desative o autolayout

[Autolayout off http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/450x400q90/674/ARs4F9.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/450x400q90/674/ARs4F9.png)

2 - Alinhe para baixo usando o Autosizing

[Autolayout off http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/450x400q90/907/dgaqDY.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/450x400q90/907/dgaqDY.png)

Assim ele vai se adaptar sempre que a tela mudar de tamanho, pois a imagem, ou qualquer outro elemento, estará alinhado com a parte inferior da tela.